# Python TypeError: object of type 'numpy.int64' has no len()

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror

Hi I'm trying to create an excel using multiple unique rows in Python.

However, I'm getting a TypeError message `(TypeError: object of type 'numpy.int64' has no len())` when executing below code.

```
data = {'ID': ['1', '2', '2', '3'],
        'Name': ['Jack', 'John', 'Steve', 'James']}
```

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:  
    for name in data['ID'].unique():
        df = data[data['ID'] == name]
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=name)
```

Here's more details to the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-73-aa4fe5c451f7> in <module>
      2     for name in df_sm['model_id_x'].unique():
      3         df = df_sm[df_sm['model_id_x'] == name]
----> 4         df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=name)
```

```
    770         # Check that sheet sheetname is <= 31. Excel limit.
--> 771         if len(sheetname) > 31:
    772             raise InvalidWorksheetName(
    773                 "Excel worksheet name '%s' must be <= 31 chars." %
```

Can someone please help with how I can fix the issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: can you add the exact error traceback ?

Comment: Ah sorry yes @tdelaney

Comment: I modified the code as an easier version. Ah, I guess I have change to string then? @tdelaney

Comment: try this - `df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=str(name))`

Answer (score 2):

Your error can't be reproduced with the code you provided (your initial code throws an error because `data` isn't a `DataFrame`; I've amended that issue).

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['1', '2', '2', '3'],
                     'Name': ['Jack', 'John', 'Steve', 'James']})

with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:
    for name in data['ID'].unique():
        df = data[data['ID'] == name]
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=name)
        # no error raised!
```

It does, however, throw your error when the column `ID` is first coerced to an integer eg with `data['ID'] = pd.to_numeric(data['ID'])`:

```
  File ... , line 807, in _check_sheetname
    if len(sheetname) > 31:

TypeError: object of type 'numpy.int64' has no len()
```

This is evidently because the `sheet_name` parameter is assumed to be a string. The code at `xlsxwriter/workbook.py` implies this assumption is made because Excel files' sheets cannot have a length greater than 31 characters. Convert your `ID` variable to a string – `data['ID'] = data['ID'].astype(str)` – and re-execute.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code with below line modified and it worked for me -

```
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=str(name))
```

Based on the data, It created 3 sheets with ID.

Answer (score 1):

Your code needed a few changes to reproduce the error (ID needs to be integers). You can make sure that the ID column is a string before processing using `astype`. And a nice enhancement is to group by ID instead of using your own mask. Both work, but groupby is a bit tighter.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'ID': [1, 2, 2, 3],
        'Name': ['Jack', 'John', 'Steve', 'James']}
        
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['ID'] = df['ID'].astype(str)

with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:  
    for name, group in df.groupby('ID'):
        group.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=name)
```